# infeasible row in Cplex C++

Tags: c++, math, model, cplex

I have a small question; I am solving MIP  Model , coded on C++ and solving by Cplex solver. I remember that when I test the model with relatively smaller instances , it was giving me "infeasibility row …."; Now ,I test the same model on a large size instance and I get the infeasibility and it does not tell me which row causes infeasibility. How can I find the which parameter or constraint causes infeasibility ? While the larger instance is tested, the presolve is performed, may it cause the infeasibility? I googled about conflict refiner but could not find a small and clear example explaining how to invoke it ? I will be very happy, if you have any suggestions or ideas

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another way to find where the infeasibility comes is to export your model as an LP file or similar, then try to solve it with the standalone cplex. It helps if you name your variables and constraints sensibly. Then you have all the interactive tools in cplex to help you find where the issues are.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ you should have a look at FeasOpt

In the documentation see

CPLEX > User's Manual for CPLEX > Infeasibility and unboundedness

[image: feasopt in cplex documentation]

If you model in OPL you could call the relaxation from concert C++ APIs

Comment: Hello @Alex, Thank you so much ,you saved my day again. Just I have a small diffciculty in the example (fesaopt) you suggested. In that example for the feasopt call they get constraint size with con.getsize() ,since they modelled the constraints in the Following manner: con.add (….) etc. However, in my model, I added the constraint in this manner: for (…) IloExp x(env) for (….) x+=S[i][j] model.add(x<0); In my case, how can I modify con.getSize () part  for calling feasOpt. Thank you in advance.